# Xamarin iOS TableViewController different class when dragged onto existing ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When you drag a Table View Controller from the Xamarin toolbox onto an existing ViewController in your storyboard, and then give it a class name, that class that is automatically created inherits from UIViewController. If you drag the Table View Controller onto an empty space on the storyboard and give it a class name, the class that is automatically created inherits from UI**Table**ViewController.

UI**Table**ViewController has a property called TableView, which has a property called Source, where you can set the DataSource for the table by giving it a UITableViewSource:

```
TableView.Source = datasource;
```

I don't know how to do this if the Table View Controller inherits from UIViewController. Can I change the class to inherit from UITableViewSource without causing problems, or does a Table View Controller embedded in another view controller have to inherit from UIViewController?

If I can't change the inheritance of the class, what is the best way to set the source of the Table View Controller that inherits from UIViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a UITableView to an existing controller, not a UITableViewController.

Comment: Are you not supposed to add a UITableViewController to another view? Strange that it even lets you do it. I thought I had it figured out (if I could change the class), but I get this error before any of my code is even executed: Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[SearchResultsTableViewController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ac9a420

Comment: A viewcontroller holds child views and has a lifecycle of its own. A view can only be a child of a viewcontroller. a viewcontroller can be added inside another one in 2 lines of code: addchildviewcontroller(vc) and Add(vc.View). A child viewcontroller can be non fullscreen, supports transitions, and should have a complex ui. So it is not common to use this type of architecture, but it is possible.

Comment: Awesome, that helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My two cents for another possible scenario. In those cases when a TableView occupies whole ViewController and there aren't any other controls/widgets in the page you can use UITableViewController instead of UIViewController. You can drag in the UITableViewController instead of the UIViewController.